# Disable text message sound when in CarPlay

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, car-integration

I don’t particularly use text message notifications and I’d rather not have them interrupt what I am listening to. I still want to keep the visual notifications, I don’t want to enable “do not disturb”. The only thing I want is to disable the notification sound, and only when in CarPlay. I can set the phone to silent, but I am wondering if there is a better way that lets me permanently disable these sounds when in CarPlay only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution that includes this silencing of texts is the standard do not disturb while driving.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208090

I also generally don’t want text messages to ring so I often just set their alert to be no sound, ever. The third option isn’t automatic, but I often do days with my entire phone in do not disturb. If I see a call, I pick it up, if not, I react when I pick up the phone and look at missed calls, voicemails and texts. Worst case, you would have to manually change either the sound or the DND settings.

- Hey Siri, turn on do not disturb.
- Hey Siri, turn off do not disturb.

Comment: Thanks. This sounds like the “official” Apple solution, but the problem is, I want to receive calls (phone/Teams/...) and I definitely do NOT want auto replies of any kind. The “do not disturb when driving” mode feels more like a relic from the pre-CarPlay days where people would pick up the phone while driving.

Comment: The “least bad” solution so far is actually turning off message sounds altogether like you did. This only leaves me with the minor inconvenience of missing texts when not driving.